# Is Salesforce still offering the Mobile Solutions Architecture Designer exam?

Tags: mobile

I cannot find the Mobile Solutions Architecture Designer certification notes anywhere on Trailhead anymore, cannot find it on WebAssessor and the link to 'find out more about this exam' from [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/mobile-solutions-architecture-maintenance-spring19/maintain-your-mobile-solutions-cert-spring19) leads to a 404: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/credentials/mobilesolutionsarchitecturedesigner

Does anyone know the background as to why it seems this cert has been pulled? I don't see it mentioned anywhere in the release notes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No salesforce is not offering this anymore. Last year those who received this certification in the past got an email saying it will be retired soon.

[image]

Comment: I know, this is very old thread. But do we know why this was discontinued. The topics of the certifications are still relevant today.